# How to quickly surround text with HTML markup in VS 2008?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, shortcut

I am working with Visual Studio 2008 editor. Is there a way to take a piece of text for example, highlight it and use shortcuts to quickly add markup?
For example, lets say I have a text, I went to: `the store` and I want to bold it, I have to type `<b>the store</b>`.  Is there a quicker and easier way to do this?

Comment: Try the following post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171132/visual-studio-how-to-quickly-wrap-text-in-html-tags/42334460#42334460

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HTML Editor just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>...

With regular text editor VS does not provide something build-in, but you can add custom macros. Something like the following will do job for you.

```
Sub MakeSelectionBold()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "<b>" + DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text + "</b>"
End Sub
```

You can then assign it to the short-cut or add button to your toolbar.

Comment: Can you create macros with c# sytnax?

Comment: The problem is that VS supports only VB macroses. Or I missed something. This is built-in functional, you can find Macro Explorer window, or Tools/Macros/...

Answer (score 32):

Select text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, type in your tags which will be autoclosed by vs, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: +1 because it's much more fluid when typing rapidly and has less "configuration" needed. 8^D

Comment: perfect! Works with zen-coding too