# How do I stop Auto-Complete during macro execution in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros

I am working on a couple of macros and whenever I am insterting text the Auto-Complete functionality is running and causing problems.

This is also described in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598062/macro-to-wrap-selected-text-with-tags-in-visual-studio).

I can manually disable the autocomplete check boxes that are interfering but that isn't really what I am looking for.

Is this where the Undo Context stuff is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will turn it off:

Dim HTMLprops As Properties

Dim aProp As EnvDTE.Property

HTMLprops = DTE.Properties("Texteditor", "HTML Specific")

aProp = HTMLprops.Item("AutoInsertCloseTag")

aProp.Value = False

Comment: Thanks... marking this correct but actually haven't tested it as the reason for needing it this time has gone away.