# asp.net mvc Razor code highlighted in dreamweaver

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, razor, dreamweaver

We have to migrate our asp.net mvc views, that use webforms view engine, into razor view engine.

The situation is that we have a group of web designers that uses dreamweaver to change the html of these files.

Do you know if there is something in dreamweaver to view correctly the razor code (i mean, hightlighted to easily read for them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for ASP.NET was dropped in Dreamweaver CS4 (current version is CS5), so any support would come only through a third-party plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Peters steps for adding cshtml to the list of editable files:

http://blog.metameister.com/blog/2011/04/08/open-new-file-types-and-add-syntax-highlighting-in-dreamweaver-cs5-on-windows-7/

Since Dreamweaver does not recognize Razor elements, this allows to edit the csHTML inside Dreamweaver, while in the design view you see the Razor parts is if they were text.

If your designers expect a design view, they might not be happy, if they are coder-designer how tweak raw (cs)html, then that might help them.

For me that is helpful, although I like the Visual Studio text editor a lot, writing text inside the page is sometimes easier with DW, for instance making some text  goes by ctrl-b inside DW while I could not figure out a way to do this in VS by shortcut.

Comment: thomas, I totally relate to having missed the ability to "wrap tags" around a selection in VS like you can so easily in Dreamweaver... until I ended up figuring out how to create a Visual Studio macro to do this! (And you can assign this to your own hotkey for fast usage.) Check out http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2009/07/visual-studio-macro-wrap-selected-text.html  and also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598062/macro-to-wrap-selected-text-with-tags-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Razor is still in beta so I would be surprised if there are any plugins available yet.

Comment: Thanks Darin, do you know more or less when will be the release?