# Visual Studio - map file extension to editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How do you map a custom file extension to an editor in Visual Studio 2013? I want to map *.js6 files to TypeScript editor but it's not working. When I one file from solution it opens with a normal text (txt) editor.

[image: Options]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Visual Studio choose which editor to use for a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263701/how-does-visual-studio-choose-which-editor-to-use-for-a-file)

Comment: Similar question yes, but there is not Typescript Editor when you open Open With dialog...

Comment: The "Add..." button invites you to add another editor into the list. Just browse for it on your computer.

Comment: I want to use Visual Studio internal editor for TypeScript. In Open With dialog you can only Add external programs.