# Visual Studio wrap selection in quotes?

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

Is there is a way to wrap a selected text block with quotes? In visual studio I have not found a extension or plugin I am just looking for a simple way to do it. Is there a way to add that functionality?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The "Surround with" option is available in Visual Studio also without ReSharper. It doesn't contain the option to wrap in quotes. But it's possible to extend the snippets with custom wrappers. Also with double quotes. To do that:

1. Click File and then click New, and choose a file type of XML.
2. On the File menu, click Save `<XMLFileName>`.
3. In the Save as box, select All Files (*.*).
4. In the File name box, enter a file name with the .snippet file name extension.
5. Click Save.
6. Add this code to the file.

Code

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>doubleQuotes</Title>
    <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
    <Shortcut>"</Shortcut>
    <Description>Wrap in double quotes</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal>
        <ID>selected</ID>
        <ToolTip>content</ToolTip>
        <Default>content</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">"$selected$"</Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Save the file.

7. Open Tools -> Code Snippets Manager.
8. In Language section select "Visual C#".
9. Click Import and browse to the snippet you just created.
10. Check My Code Snippets and click Finish and then OK.

To use it: Select text -> right click -> select "Surround with..." -> My Code Snippets -> doubleQuotes

Alternatively: Select text -> hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> -> My Code Snippets -> doubleQuotes

I got the idea for this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2879206/3330348) where the author shows how to wrap code in custom HTML tags.

Answer (score 4):

This might be overkill, but ReSharper offers a utility called **Surround With** that offers a templated mechanism for surrounding blocks of text.  It doesn't look like they have a template out of the box for quotes, but you should be able to easily create one:

[image]

Plugin Description:  https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Applying_Templates__Surrounding_Code_Fragments_with_Templates.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command (C# language) with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to wrap a selected text block with quotes:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        ts.Text = '"' + ts.Text + '"';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

**This is for Visual Studio Code**

> Windows: IDE Visual Studio Code

1. Select the text you want to wrap
2. **Hold on <kbd>Shift</kbd> key** and **Press <kbd>"</kbd> key**, it will wrap a text with double quotes.

( In Addition you can also wrap with <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>{</kbd>   )

Comment: Thanks, @mathan it really works in VS Code(on Mac M1)!!

Comment: Question about Visual studio

Comment: This is about a different IDE than the OP asked about.

Comment: I don't understand why Visual Studio 2022 doesn't have this.