# Wrap variable in function call Visual Studio keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a keyboard shortcut in either Visual Studio, Resharper or another extension to automatically wrap something in a function call? Trying to become more of a keyboard wizard and it's frustrating that I can't find a solution to this since this is something I have to do often, especially writing unit tests.

Example:

Original

```
{ QualifiedName.Root, EqualsTestResult.HashCodeEqualsOnly },
```

New:

```
{ QualifiedName.CreateAutomaticallyResolveUpQualifiedName(QualifiedName.Root), EqualsTestResult.HashCodeEqualsOnly },
```

Comment: I would suggest looking in to either `Code Snippets` or [Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio) - Both of these are an essential part of my environment

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757631/visual-studio-wrap-selection-in-quotes

Comment: That seems close, but the string to surround with is hard coded into the snippet

Comment: Have you tried "Extract Method" in ReSharper?