# Is there a Visual Studio shortcut to give multiple lines html tags at the beginning and end of the line?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to find a good answer for this.  I want to know if there's a quick way to add both the opening and closing HTML tags far multiple lines at the same time.

Lets say I have a list of text that I want to surround with a p tag:

```
text line 1
text line 2
text line 3
text line 4
text line 5
```

I can hold the 'alt' key and click to the beginning of each line and start typing my tag.  But then VS auto fills the closing p tag right beside the opening tag like this:

```
<p></p>text line 1
<p></p>text line 2
<p></p>text line 3
<p></p>text line 4
<p></p>text line 5
```

Then I have to drag each closing tag to the end of the line.  Is there a quick way that I can highlight multiple lines of text and give each line an opening and closing tag at the same time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191463/how-do-i-wrap-a-selection-with-an-html-tag-in-visual-studio/2879206 - not sure there is something for multiple lines of text though

Comment: That's closer than anything I've found, but I was still kinda hoping for a better solution.   Maybe there isn't one. Thank you!

Comment: Visual Studio, or Visual Studio Code? Asking because both are tagged.

Comment: Visual Studio Code.  I thought they were the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the Emmet plugin.

[read this short article about Wrapping individual lines in Emmet.](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#wrapping-individual-lines)

Comment: Thank you!  If someone is reading this in the future the extension that worked for me on VS Code is called Emmet Keybindings by Andres Gutierrez.